# Replacing NaN pixel values in GeoTIFF using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I was wondering if there is a easy way (GDAL) to replace GeoTIFF pixels that are `-nan` with a different value (e.g. 100)?

I tried

```
gdal_calc.py -A my.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A-(A==-nan)*(-nan - 100))"
```

following some examples, but this doesn't work because `NaN` messes with arithmetic operations and turns everything it touches into a `NaN`.

Any pointers to alternatives?

Ideally a command line as with `gdal_calc.py`.

Comment: NaN (Not a Number) is a database value... what data type are your pixels? I believe that IEEEE floating point supports INF and NaN, perhaps if you multiply by a fixed value and output as Int32 then divide by the same as Float32. You are right that these values totally muck with arithmetic operations, but how did they get there in the first place? Perhaps you could try an always true statement like A>-9999999 which should always return true for values and if that doesn't work then use the opposite A<99999999 but I have a feeling that those values will stick.

Comment: The issue is I don't even know what's the real value. I was given the GeoTIFF. I used `gdallocationinfo my.tif 1 1 -valonly`, and it only returns `-nan`.

Comment: The data type is 64bit float

Comment: If they're NaN I think it would be safe to convert them to NODATA, try the answer that I have submitted, you need to find how the value is stored in the ASC by locating one value; from memory I think it's -1#QNaN. If the file is small you can use notepad but for big rasters (more than a few MB) then you will need to find a better text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the flag `--NoDataValue=NODATAVALUE` to replace NoDataValue.

See the third example [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html)

Comment: This does not work with A/B, where B=0

Comment: Then do `A/(B+(B==0))` or similar

Comment: Please provide a full example based on OP's commandline.

Comment: The 3rd example is now about adding files together. The most relevant current example seems to be _"Set values of zero and below to null:"_ `gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A>0)" --NoDataValue=0`. Which is good but doesn't address situation where you have valid negative values.

Answer (score 9):

Use NumPy's [`nan_to_num` function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) to substitute NaN values to 0 (the default):

```
$ gdal_calc.py -A nan.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="nan_to_num(A)"
```

If you have NumPy version 1.17 or later, you can specify a different value, e.g. -9999:

```
$ gdal_calc.py -A nan.tif --outfile=result2.tif --calc="nan_to_num(A, nan=-9999)" --NoDataValue=-9999
```

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the most annoying things I have found in trying to deal with `gdal_calc.py` (or the raster calculator GUI).  Anywhere there is a nodata in any of the inputs the output gets set to nodata.  So let's say you have a mask that has values inside a region you want to modify, and nodata outside.  The result will be that the pixels inside the region are correctly modified, and the pixels outside are all set to nodata.  That's no good if you want to modify part of a map while leaving the rest alone.

What you need is a mask with values inside the region and valid data zeros (or some other tag value) outside.  No problem, you say, I just need to change the nodatas in the mask layer to zeros.  Should be a snap.  I have a raster calculator.  Turns out it's not so easy.

When I tried googling an answer to this question the most common advice was, here's how to do it with GRASS or Numpy, or some other plugin.  If I'm trying to do something that should take me less than 5 minutes, and someone's advice is first install and learn how to use a completely different tool, I stop reading immediately.

You can do it with GDAL.  There are two scripts that you will need.  doktoreas' answer about the `--NoDataValue` option of `gdal_calc.py` is part of the answer.  This changes all of the nodata pixels to have that value, and sets the metadata so that value is the nodata value.  If you just do that, the raster calculator will still treat them as nodata and produce nodata in the result.  Next you have to use the `-a_nodata` option of `gdal_translate`.  This changes the metadata of what value is treated as nodata without changing the values of pixels that have the old nodata value.  This leaves your pixels with a numeric value that is not treated as nodata.

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=intermediate.tif --calc="A" --NoDataValue=0
gdal_translate intermediate.tif result.tif -a_nodata -1
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be totally tedious but if you convert to [Esri ASC](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm) (GDAL_Translate -of [AAIGRID](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html)) which is a text based format and then open in a really good text editor like Notepad++ or VI/[VIm](http://www.vim.org/about.php), or write a python script, you can replace bad values using find & replace.

Then save & close the file and translate to a GeoTiff