# Change NODATA values to 0 in Qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, data, qgis-2.8

I know this question has been asked already in this forum, but I couldn't find an easy (for me, a rookie) solution for my problem.
I have an RGB 3 band file which, in some pixels, has i.e.

```
R no data
G 147
B 147
```

This creates problems in the visualization of the raster. I'd like to know how to change those values to 0, enabling the colours to be  correctly displayed again.
I tried to use an algorithm in the processing tab, but it says SAGA algorithms are not supported by multiband layers. Also I've seen many using GRASS tools, but I really have no clue on how to use GRASS, so I would need a step by step explanation. Consider I am still a newbie with this software so, if possible, I'd like use the easiest method.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @RiccardoBoniardi! There's also GDAL which has the **Fill nodata** tool, you could access this from the _Processing Toolbox_.

Comment: Some gdal approaches suggested [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134084/gdal-how-to-replace-nan-pixel-values-in-geotiff) and GRASS/QGIS Raster plugin options [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33764/how-to-change-null-values-raster-values-to-0-in-qgis)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the welcome. I looked into my processing toolbox but i have no such tool as fill no data. I guess i miss some plugin or something (my version is 2.8.4). I also read that the fill no data uses interpolation as a method to fill nodata, but i want them to be replaced with 0 exactly, so i dunno if that method would be suitable. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: @RiccardoBoniardi - There should be a menu at the bottom of your _Processing Toolbox_ which probably says **Simplified interface**. If so, change this to **Advanced interface** to obtain a lot more tools. But yes, you are correct in that interpolation is used for the **Fill nodata** tool. You should probably have listed which questions you looked at to stop others suggesting the same ones :)

Answer (score 5):

As Joseph suggested, the `Fill nodata` tool solves your problem. It replaces NoData values with 0's, in the band of your choice.

You can find it either in `Raster > Analysis`, or (with a slightly different interface) `Processing > Toolbox > GDAL/OGR > [GDAL] Analysis` (in QGIS 2.8).

Edit: of course, this assumes that GDAL is correctly installed and can be "seen" by QGIS.

Edit 2: as mentionned, `Fill nodata` outputs only the processed band. A possible solution would be to split your bands (there's a SAGA tool called `Split RGB bands` in the processing toolbox), then apply the `Fill nodata` tool, then merge your bands back (`Raster > Miscellaneous > Merge`).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. I tried the "raster analysis" tool, but the output file i got was single band, so its still not displayed correctly. As i said, the original TIF file is a 3 band file, and i'd need to change all nodata values to 0 for each of the 3 bands. Maybe i did something wrong, but there wasnt much to click =)

Comment: You're right, this is a bit more complicated than expected. I updated my answer, hope this will work for you.

Comment: I will try this method, but i also might have found a workaround. I converted the TIF to a PNG and this fixed the colour visualization problem ofc. Now, i dont really need the 3 bands, i just need a correctly visualized image, probel is, the PNG is not georeferenced. Now, i know there is the geo referencing tool, but i'd like to keep the exact referencing the TIF has, which i can see in the metadata. Is there a way to define image corners coordinates and not arbitrary points for a raster layer?

Comment: @RiccardoBoniardi: there is a plugin called [GeorefExport](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeorefExport) that should generate a georeferenced PNG.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i couldn't find the plugin in the "manage and install plugin" tab, so i downloaded from the developer page, but i don't know how to install it (its not a .dll file as the plugins inside qgis folder). If you could suggest me how to install it, i'd give it a try. Thanks again

Comment: @RiccardoBoniardi: you have to check the box "Show also experimental plugins" in the Settings tab of the "manage and install plugin" tool.

Comment: i tried the plugin but unfortunately it converts the NODATA pixels into 255 pixels for each of the 3 bands, and there is no turning back since i actually need the white pixels (255 for all bands) in the original file, but if all NODATA are visualized as white, the view is even more wrong. Thanks for the try anyway

Comment: I also tried the SPLIT RGB command but it returns me an error and cant produce the 3 layers for the bands.. i am afraid i will actually need to georeference manually.. The main problem is that in the georeferencing tool, the image merges with the whie background and i cant see the real corners of it.. this is why i was wondering if there was a way to precisely assign coords only for the corners.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm out of advices... You can however change the background color in Project > Project Properties > General.

Comment: Well, those were useful advices anyway, i will put them to good use. Maybe i will be able to use some script in the future to perform this action in a more professional way. Thanks alot